# Not add +count for a first for loop (in nested for loop case)

Tags: java, iteration

I have an iterative function with 3 for loops. I use an array and want to count after how much times instructions count of iterative function. But the loop I used for array, also causes count to increase by 1. How to remove this. Here is my code:

```
package itrative.methods;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItrativeMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j, k;
        int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0;
        int[] n = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        for (int m = 0; m < n.length; m++) {

            for (i = n[m] / 2; i <= n[m]; i++) {
                count1++;
                for (j = 1; j <= n[m] / 2; j++) {
                    count2++;
                    for (k = 1; k <= 100; k = k * 2) {
                        count3++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count1 + "  |  " + count2 + "  |  " + count3);
        }
    }

}
```

[These are the results of this code (wrong)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxNLb.png)
[Correct results at n=10 without using array loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqSkU.png)

Comment: The question can be improved by posting the results you get, and describe why the results are incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, for late editing but I was busy in pondering...

Comment: Consider just count1 for now (which currently counts the 'i' loop).  Can you please explain why it should be 6?

Comment: When n=10, we have **for(i=5 ; i<=10 ; i++)**. Thus, loop executes at i=(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10). These are 6 values for which loop continues and "count becomes 6". Now, when loop executes for i=5, the next for loop **for(j=1 ; j<=5 ; j++)** executes 5 times and for 1 execution of loop 2, third loop executes 7 time (calculated) and thus we have:     _7*5*6 = 210_

Comment: Can you just describe the expected and actual output instead of posting images? And please edit your question instead of adding comments. Not all comments are always shown initially. Make it easy for people to get all information. Make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to count the values during each iteration.

```
public class ItrativeMethods {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j, k;
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0;
    int[] n = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    for (int m = 0; m < n.length; m++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        count3 = 0;
        for (i = n[m] / 2; i <= n[m]; i++) {
            count1++;
            for (j = 1; j <= n[m] / 2; j++) {
                count2++;
                for (k = 1; k <= 100; k = k * 2) {
                    count3++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count1 + "  |  " + count2 + "  |  " + count3);
    }
}

}
```

Producing output:

```
2  |  0  |  0
2  |  2  |  14
3  |  3  |  21
3  |  6  |  42
4  |  8  |  56
4  |  12  |  84
5  |  15  |  105
5  |  20  |  140
6  |  24  |  168
6  |  30  |  210
```

To get totals as well:

```
public class ItrativeMethods {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j, k;
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, count3 = 0;
    int count1Total = 0, count2Total = 0, count3Total = 0;
    int[] n = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    for (int m = 0; m < n.length; m++) {
        count1 = 0;
        count2 = 0;
        count3 = 0;
        for (i = n[m] / 2; i <= n[m]; i++) {
            count1++;
            count1Total++;
            for (j = 1; j <= n[m] / 2; j++) {
                count2++;
                count2Total++;
                for (k = 1; k <= 100; k = k * 2) {
                    count3++;
                    count3Total++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count1 + "  |  " + count2 + "  |  " + count3);
    }
    System.out.println("Totals");
    System.out.println(count1Total + "  |  " + count2Total + "  |  " + count3Total);
}

}
```

Comment: But I want many values, that's the reason I used array. Here, you got only one output, at n=10. How, I get output at n=1,2,3.......10.

Comment: Please review now.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks man... Is it possible to get final iteration counts for every value. I'll try to get this; if possible by this method

Comment: Ohh! This was so simple. Why I didn't think like that, putting 0 after every loop is nice... Thanks man.

Comment: Yes.  It just took a bit to understand what the requirement was.  Are you now able to check off that the answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct.... I checked and also used  this method for other iterations also. This helps me great to find bigO at iterative formula.

Comment: Perfect.  Happy to help.  There is a step you should take now.  There is a check mark beside the answer (to the left) - the person posting the question is supposed to check this, to show that the answer is correct.  The check mark turns green.  This informs other people not to keep solving the problem.  Can you do this?  thanks.